# Aggregate error on join clause (selecting MIN date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find out the salary of staff when they first started, and in order to do this I am using a join function to match the employee start date in one table (EMPOS aka POSI) to employee starting salary date in another table (EMSAL aka SAL) to retrieve the salary amount at the date of starting the role. I am wanting to use the MIN function in order to select the lowest date (starting date) from EMPOS aka POSI and whatever that date is to match with the date of salary date and amount in the EMSAL aka SAL table.

I am running into the following error

> - An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column
>     being aggregated is an outer reference.

Here is my code summarized -

```
Select CS.Name, SAL.SalaryAmount 
FROM CurrentStaff as CS

LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPOS as POSI ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = POSI.DET_NUMBER COLLATE 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AND CS.POS_STARTC = POSI.POS_START

LEFT OUTER JOIN EMSAL SAL on CS.DET_NUMBERA = SAL.DET_NUMBER COLLATE 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AND SAL.SMN_DATE 
= (SELECT MIN(POSI.POS_START) FROM EMPOS)
```

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions or require further info, please let me know :)

Cheers!

Comment: This looks like SQL Server, but in any case please remove the incompatible database tags from your question.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to replace your join to the `EMPOS` table with a subquery which finds the earlier date for each employee.  Then, use that subquery to restrict to the very first record per employee which you want.

```
SELECT
    CS.Name, SAL.SalaryAmount
FROM CurrentStaff AS CS
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DET_NUMBER, MIN(POS_START) AS first_start
    FROM EMPOS
    GROUP BY DET_NUMBER
) POSI
    ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = POSI.DET_NUMBER COLLATE
        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AND CS.POS_STARTC = POSI.POS_START
LEFT JOIN EMSAL SAL
    ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = SAL.DET_NUMBER AND
       SAL.SMN_DATE = POSI.first_start COLLATE 
        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, this has worked. I ammended the code slightly. I removed the Collate between cs.pos_start and posi.pos_start. Also removed collate at the end of the query.

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT DET_NUMBER, MIN(POS_START) as first_start
    FROM EMPOS
    GROUP BY DET_NUMBER) POSI 
 ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = POSI.DET_NUMBER COLLATE 
    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
 LEFT OUTER JOIN EMSAL SAL
      ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = SAL.DET_NUMBER COLLATE 
        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  AND
       SAL.SMN_DATE = POSI.first_start

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CS.Name, SAL.SalaryAmount 
FROM CurrentStaff as CS

LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPOS as POSI ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = POSI.DET_NUMBER COLLATE 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AND CS.POS_STARTC = POSI.POS_START

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM EMSAL 
     WHERE SMN_DATE = (SELECT MIN(POS_START) 
                       FROM EMPOS)
    ) SAL 
on CS.DET_NUMBERA = SAL.DET_NUMBER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have used this query, however it returns only 1 row for the minimum date in the table, i'm after the minimum date for each employee in the table. I tried to use GROUP BY but this failed too - –
I suppose it doesn't make sense as the SMN Date has to equal only a date, and this date needs to be when a particular employee first started (POS_START) which would be a record in EMPOS

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong table alias in the subquery:

```
SELECT CS.Name, SAL.SalaryAmount 
FROM CurrentStaff CS LEFT OUTER JOIN
     EMPOS POSI
     ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = POSI.DET_NUMBER COLLATE 
 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AND 
        CS.POS_STARTC = POSI.POS_START LEFT OUTER JOIN
     EMSAL SAL 
     ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = SAL.DET_NUMBER COLLATE 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AND 
        SAL.SMN_DATE = (SELECT MIN(POSI2.POS_START) FROM EMPOS POSI2);
```

However, I find `subqueries in the`ON` clause to be hard to follow, so I would write this as:

```
SELECT CS.Name, SAL.SalaryAmount 
FROM CurrentStaff CS LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT POSI.*, MIN(POSI.POS_START) OVER () as MIN_POS_START
      FROM EMPOS POSI
     ) POSI
     ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = POSI.DET_NUMBER COLLATE 
 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AND 
        CS.POS_STARTC = POSI.POS_START LEFT OUTER JOIN
     EMSAL SAL 
     ON CS.DET_NUMBERA = SAL.DET_NUMBER COLLATE 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AND 
        SAL.SMN_DATE = POSI.MIN_POS_START) ;
```

That said, I'm also surprised that you want the *overall* minimum and not the minimum per employee.  So, the `MIN()` should probably be:

```
MIN(POSI.POS_START) OVER (PARTITION BY POSI.DET_NUMBER)
```

Similarly, your subquery should have a correlation clause.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I've tried your 2nd query and this has worked! Good pick up on the pos_start date (that I wanted minimum per employee).